# Loading a large ui with many callbacks takes long in Shiny. Is there a way to make it faster or at least have a loading symbol?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny-app with a complex ui. I use many divs and only show the ones that are currently requested by the user. Let me give you an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
N <- 400
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "plot_chooser",
        choices = 1:N,
        label = "Choose plot to display"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      "Top",
      lapply(1:N, function(i){
        hidden(div(
          id = paste0("plot_div",i),
          plotOutput(outputId = paste0("plot",i))
        ))
      }),
      "bottom"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tictoc::tic(msg = "Loading app")
  lapply(1:N, function(i){
    output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot({
      Sys.sleep(1)
      ggplot(iris)+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+ggtitle(i)
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot_chooser,{
    tictoc::tic(msg = "Showing and hiding stuff")
    i <- input$plot_chooser
    for (j in setdiff(1:N, i)) {
      shinyjs::hide(paste0("plot_div", j))
    }
    shinyjs::show(paste0("plot_div", i))
    tictoc::toc()
  })
  tictoc::toc()
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

In this app there 400 plots that take a long time to load (I simulated that using `Sys.sleep(1)`). This is the reason, I decided to use many divs instead of a uioutput. This way, already loaded plots do not have to be computed again, only displayed. I find this a nice feature. However, there is a penalty: When the app starts up, it is rendered and displayed on piece after another. You can see that if you look closely at the "top"/"bottom" texts: They are there from the very beginning and then after 1.89 seconds (in my case) suddenly get torn apart by the now appearing plot-divs (and the plot appears 1 second later).

(tictoc is a library for measuring time in R, in case you are wondering. Playing around with it gave the following console-output:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6821
Loading app: 1.89 sec elapsed
Showing and hiding stuff: 0.19 sec elapsed
Showing and hiding stuff: 0.2 sec elapsed
...
```

)

Please have a look at the app and play around a bit.

My questions now are:

- Is there a way to make the loading time for starting the app faster?
- Is there a way to make the flickering at the start of the app disappear? Meaning that instead of first having a wrong (incomplete) UI, you have a waiting screen or something like that?
- Is there a way to make changing between the views faster and with less flickering (least important to me, this is not a problem in my real app)?

Comment: Are these reactive plots? If not (as in your example), you could generate them outside the app.

Comment: They are reactive. They depend on filters that the user sets during the life time of the app.

Comment: `withProgress()` is your friend see: https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/progress/ . The shinycssloaders library is pretty good as well: https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders

Comment: Unfortunately these tools only work once the ui has been generated, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the `plotOutput`s in a div with height `400px` (the default height of `plotOutput`) to avoid the problem with top/bottom, and you can use `shinycssloaders::withSpinner` to have a loading indicator.

```r
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      "Top",
      div(
        style = "height: 400px",
        lapply(1:N, function(i) {
          hidden(div(
            id = paste0("plot_div", i),
            withSpinner(plotOutput(outputId = paste0("plot", i)))
          ))
        }) 
      ),
      "bottom"
    )
  )
```

[image]

---

## Edit

You can also highyly improve the loop hide/show. There's only one plot shown so there's no need to hide N-1 plots:

```r
  Shown <- reactiveVal(1) # the first plot shown is 1
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_chooser,{
    tictoc::tic(msg = "Showing and hiding stuff")
    i <- input$plot_chooser
    shinyjs::hide(paste0("plot_div", Shown()))
    shinyjs::show(paste0("plot_div", i))
    Shown(i)
    tictoc::toc()
  })
```

Comment: But this is only helping for the 1 second that the renderPlot takes, not the .2 seconds the plots need to get hidden and reshown. Set N=1000 to see this effect even stronger. The flickering is the same in my app (although in your gif it looks as if there is no flickering... what is the time displayed by `tictoc(msg="showing and hiding stuff")`)

Comment: The start of the app still looks the same: You see the incomplete UI for very long

Comment: @Noskario Sorry, no flickering effect for me, even with N=1000. In the RStudio browser or in Chrome.

Comment: For the start-up, you can use `shinybusy::busy_start_up` to have a loading indicator.

Comment: Interesting, for me both Firefox and Edge make the divs disappear and thus the "buttom" jumps to "Top" and then back down. Thanks for shinybusy::busy_start_up, I am going to look that up.

Comment: @Noskario Please see my edit. Now the tictoc takes 0.001 seconds.